# '(' for function-style cast or construction type Xcode error

Tags: c++, xcode, function, parameters, void

```
This is where I get error:
 calcScore(double score1,double score2, double score3, double score4, double score5);
```

here is the my code, I do not know how to fix the error; I am not sure what the error means. I've tried looking at examples in textbook, and online but I am still confused; this is first assignment where we have to use function

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void getJudgesData();
void calcScore();

int main()
{
    double scoreAverage=-9;
    double score1=-9.0;
    double score2=-9.0;
    double score3=-9.0;
    double score4=-9.0;
    double score5=-9.0;

    getJudgesData();

    calcScore(double score1,double score2, double score3, double score4, double score5);

    return 0;
}

 // getJudgesData Program
void getJudgesData(double &score1, double &score2, double &score3, double &score4, double &score5)
{

    do
    {
        cout << "Enter judges score: ";
        cin >> score1;
        do
        {
            if (score1 < 0 || score1 >10)
            {
                cout << "Score has to range from 0-10 \n";
                cout << "Please enter a valid score: ";
                cin >> score1;
            }
        }while (score1<0 || score1 >10);
   }
    while (score1<0 || score1 >10);

    do
    {
        cout << "Enter judges score: ";
        cin >> score2;
        do
        {
            if (score2 < 0 || score2 >10)
            {
                cout << "Score has to range from 0-10 \n";
                cout<< "Please enter a valid score: ";
                cin >> score2;
            }
        }while (score2 <0 || score2 >10);
    }
    while (score2<0 || score2 >10);

    do
    {
        cout << "Enter judges score: ";
        cin >> score3;
        do
        {
            if (score3 < 0 || score3 >10)
           {
                cout << "Score has to range from 0-10 \n";
                cout << "Please enter a valid score: ";
                cin >> score3;
            }
        }while (score3 < 0 || score3 >10);
    }
    while (score3<0 || score3 >10);

    do
    {
        cout << "Enter judges score: ";
        cin >> score4;
        do
        {
            if (score4 < 0 || score4 >10)
            {
                cout << "Score has to range from 0-10 \n";
                cout << "Please enter a valid score: ";
                cin >> score4;
            }
        }while (score4 < 0 || score4 >10);
    }
    while (score4<0 || score4 >10);

    do
    {
        cout << "Enter judges score: ";
        cin >> score5;
        do
        {
            if (score5 < 0 || score5 >10)
            {
                cout << "Score has to range from 0-10 \n";
                cout << "Please enter a valid score: ";
                cin >> score5;
            }
        }while (score5 < 0 || score5 >10);
    }
    while (score5<0 || score5 >10);

    return;
}

//Start of calcScore
void calcScore( double score1, double score2, double score3, double score4,double score5)
{
    double average;

    average = (score1+score2+score3+score4+score5)/ 5;

    return;
}
```

Comment: You're calling the function with values, so you don't need to specify the datatypes i.e. just do `calcScore(score1,...)`. Also, doesn't `getJudgesData` need some arguments to be passed in?

Comment: @shree.pat18 When I remove the datatype (double), I get a new error that says "No matching function for call to calcScore"

Comment: Well your function signature at the top does not have any arguments but the actual function body does. You need to sync up the 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's deal with your error first: as @shree.pat18 points out in the comments, you are calling a function and trying to give the type of the parameters. This isn't allowed. C++ *knows* the type of the parameters because you declared them previously. You can call `calcScore` like so:

```
double score1=-9.0;
double score2=-9.0;
double score3=-9.0;
double score4=-9.0;
double score5=-9.0;

getJudgesData();

calcScore(score1, score2, score3, score4, score5);
```

However, that brings you to a new problem: At the time of compilation, the compiler doesn't know about a function called `calcScore` which takes 5 parameters of type `double`.

You are declaring two functions called `calcScore`: one is simply declared and not defined with no parameters, and the other is declared and defined with parameters:

```
// just a declaration. This function has no definition and will not link
void calcScore();
```

and

```
// declared and defined
void calcScore( double score1, double score2, double score3, double score4,double score5)
{
}
```

You can remove the first declaration of `calcScore` since I assume you don't need both, and change it to be:

```
void calcScore(double score1, double score2, double score3, double score4, double score5);
```

Now when you try to invoke `calcScore` and pass in 5 `double` within your `main`, the compiler will know what function you are referring to.